# Tengo un problema al enviar un formulario de contacto con PHP

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Estoy intentando enviar un formulario con PHP, antes estaba bien y funcionaba ahora de pronto ya no funciona.
la version de PHP del servidor es 7.1.

Necesito su ayuda para poder enviar los formularios que llenan los clientes a un correo gmail.

**FORMULARIO**

```html
<form data-toggle="validator"   method="post" action="contacto.php" accept-charset="utf-8 ">
<div class="row formulario    ">
 <div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "nombre" class="  fontverdana"> Nombre </label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name="nombre"  id = "nombre" placeholder = "Ingrese su Nombre " required><br>
   </div>
 <div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "ape" class="  fontverdana"> Apellido </label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "ape"  name ="ape" placeholder = "Ingrese su Apellido " required><br>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <label for="email" class="  fontverdana"> Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder = "Ingrese su Email" required><br>
      </div>
<div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "telefono" class="  fontverdana">Telèfono</label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "telefono"  name="telefono"   placeholder = "Ingrese su Telèfono" required><br>
   </div>
    <div class = "col-md-12">
      <label for = "mensaje" class="  fontverdana"> Mensaje:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder = "Escriba Su Consulta" required></textarea>
<br>
  </div>
    <div class = "col-md-12">
  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg marginlastmin  "> <span class="glyphicon icon-envelope"></span> <strong> Enviar</strong></button>
  <p class="tinytex">
Al Hacer clic en Enviar, Usted manifiesta su consentimiento para que Dnp Corp realice el tratamiento de sus datos personales, conforme a las <a href="terminos.html" target="blank"> Condiciones y Términos detallados en la sección Política de Tratamiento de Datos Personales.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
</div></form>
```

**Script PHP**

```js
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>Consulta Web</title>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<?php 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$ape = $_POST['ape'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$para = 'emaildestino@mail.pe';
$titulo = 'Consulta Via Web';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo =  "Nombre: $nombre $ape\n E-Mail: $email\n Telefono: $telefono\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
window.location.href = 'http://www.perulaptops.pe/gracias.html';
</script>";
} else {
echo 'Falló el envio';
}
}
?>
```

`

Comment: ¿Que problema tienes?

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste logs? ¿Qué encontraste? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento actual del formulario? (no funciona es un poco... genérico) :)

Comment: El problema es que no envia el correo al gmail destino.

Comment: Sabes que error te indica, en tu log?

Comment: No hay errores referentes en los logs

Comment: ¿Si haces un `echo $msjCorreo;`  sale todo correcto en pantalla? ¿Probaste a enviarte un mensaje a ti mismo y revisar la carpeta spam?

Comment: El echo $msjCorreo; sale correcto, no llega mensaje a ningun correo que coloque.

Comment: ¿Pero te sale el alert `Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.`  o sale `Falló en el envío`?

Comment: se me muestra el contenido del mensaje y mensaje enviado.